# Gulp plugin not pulling all files

Tags: gulp

Trying to use main-bower-files and filters to copy files from bower_components. So far its working except for less. All it is taking is bootstrap.less and not all the .less files.

```
var gulp       = require('gulp'),
        gutil      = require('gulp-util'),
        gulpFilter = require('gulp-filter'),
        bowerMain  = require('main-bower-files'),
        concat     = require('gulp-concat'),
        uglify     = require('gulp-uglify'),
        rename     = require('gulp-rename');

// Group tasks
gulp.task('default', function() {
    gutil.log("Test");
});

// Individual tasks
gulp.task('bower', function() {
    var jsFilter  = gulpFilter('*.js', {restore: true}),
            lessFilter = gulpFilter('*.less');

    return gulp.src(bowerMain())
        // JS
        .pipe(jsFilter)
        .pipe(concat('scripts.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js')) 
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(rename({
            suffix: '.min'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js')) 
        .pipe(jsFilter.restore)

        // CSS
        .pipe(lessFilter)
        //.pipe(concat('styles.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./temp'))
});
```

If I gutil.log bowerMain and its not showing all the less files. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you check the main section of [bower.json for bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/bower.json) it shows below

```
 "main": [
    "less/bootstrap.less",
    "dist/js/bootstrap.js"
  ],
```

its containing only boostrap.less hence you see only that one less file. Hence nothing wrong with what you are doing...

you can override the main section of boostrap in your bower.json to include other less files if you want, read on how to do it [here](https://roots.io/using-bootstrap-with-bower-how-to-override-bower-packages/)